# Añadir Evento click Angular innerHtml

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml

Buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente: estoy insertando codigo HTML a una pagina de esta forma:

```
let divsucursal:any=document.getElementById(`Sucursal1`);
let buttonscreate="";


    buttonscreate=`<span class='buttonRoles'>boton <i (click)='eliminarRol(1,1)' class=' fa elimRol fa-times-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>`;

divsucursal.innerHTML=buttonscreate;
```

Entonces hay un icono que le tiene el evento **(click)**, el html se añade pero el evento **click** no funciona porque se añade de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no me ejecuta el evento click de ese elemento, espero me ayuden les agradeceria mucho

Comment: no puedes añader un evento `(click)` así porque esto se tiene que compilar a js que pueda entender el nevagador y esto como se añade dinamicamente pues no se compila. Podrias poner el boton en la template y funcionaria. `(click)` al fin y al cabo es una directiva por lo tanto, sino se compila previamente a un event handler de js no va a funcionar. Puedes usar `onclick="mifunc"` pero no recomiendo hacer esto porque pierdes el change detection y todas las ventajas de angular.

Comment: En Angular, nunca es buena idea tocar directamente el DOM. Angular trabaja con un DOM virtual donde hace todas las operaciones de *prerendering* y presentación. Te sugiero que, si necesitas renderizar elementos dinamicamente uses [`ng-template` y `ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template).

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como comenta [@ajuni880](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/156639/ajuni880) para que funcione el compilado en runtime, es necesario hacerlo en el ngAfterViewInit de Angular

Adjunto un ejemplito de stackblitz para que veas como se hace el binding: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbsocj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) {}

  public asd(){
    var contentString = 'Click here for more information <button (click)="navigate()">Navigate here</button>'; 
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.innerHTML = contentString;
  }

  public navigate() {
    console.log("eeeehnnananaa");
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => { this.navigate();});
  }
```

En stackoverflow está la respuesta original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082441/6329540